# How to pass argument to Event Handler in Xamarin IOS

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xamarin, eventhandler

How to pass string argument to EventHandler?

ViewController(A)
Written Event Handler

```
    public event EventHandler ValueChanged; 

    void ResponseCompleted(object sender, CommonCode.ResponseEventArgs e){
        this.InvokeOnMainThread (delegate { 

        if (ValueChanged != null) {
        ValueChanged (this, new EventArgs (e.ResponseData));
// e.ResponseData is an String datatype.
         }
     });
    }
```

ViewController(B)

```
relatedDataSource.ValueChanged += delegate {
 Get Response Data from ViewControllerA
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use generic EventHandler. For example:

```
public event EventHandler<string> ValueChanged;

void ResponseCompleted(object sender, CommonCode.ResponseEventArgs e){
    this.InvokeOnMainThread (delegate { 

    var handler = ValueChanged;
    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, e.ResponseData);
    });
}

relatedDataSource.ValueChanged += (s, responseData) => {
    //Your data is in responseData variable
}
```